# Get Key and Value of a Dictionary for max N values of the Dictionary

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

I have seen many posts, which use the below:

```
sorted(iterable, key=keyfunc, reverse=True)[0]
```

But how do I get both key and value ?

The above returns key only.

Should I get the keys and iterate as done in the below code or is there a simpler way to do it ?

```
topn_dict = sorted(similarity_dict, key=similarity_dict.get, reverse=True)[:5]
topn_pairs = {k: similarity[k] for k in topn_dict}
print (topn_pairs)
```

Edit:

```
similarity_dict = {a: 5.1, b: 4.99, c: 8.72, d: 6.34, e: 2.3, f: 9.1}

I would like the output as following for top 3:
f - 9.1
c - 8.72
d - 6.34
```

Comment: Max of the values of the dictionary. In the given example, 5 is max, followed by 4 and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can sort and re-create a dict directly:

```
topn_dict = dict(sorted(similarity.items(), key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True))
```

without an explicit `key` (or `key=lambda x: x[0]`) this will sort according to the keys; the version above sorts the values.

note that `dict`s are sorted only on python >= 3.?. in older versions `dict`s are not sorted anyway. (**update from [DeepSapce](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1453822/deepspace)**: starting from python 3.7 you can rely on that.)

for your example you can use:

```
topn_dict = dict(sorted(similarity_dict.items(), key=lambda x: x[1], 
                        reverse=True)[:5])
print(topn_dict)
```

Comment: 3.7* before that  (3.6, not even sure about 3.5) it was only an implementation detail.

Comment: @DeepSpace: oh, thanks for that. my memory is a bit shaky about the version it got changed. ...obviously!